# discord.gateway: shard id none heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds. loop thread traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, runtime-error

I was testing my discord bots commands, and the bot would just think forever. Checked the logs and received the title error. Here is my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import time
import json
import platform
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

class Client(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('.'), intents=discord.Intents().all())

        self.cogslist = ["cogs.whitelist"]

    async def setup_hook(self):
      for ext in self.cogslist:
        await self.load_extension(ext)

    async def on_ready(self):
        prfx = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S UTC", time.gmtime()))
        print(prfx + " Logged in as " + self.user.name)
        print(prfx + " Bot ID " + str(self.user.id))
        print(prfx + " Discord Version " + discord.__version__)
        print(prfx + " Python Version " + str(platform.python_version()))
        synced = await self.tree.sync()
        print(prfx + " Slash CMDs Synced " + str(len(synced)) + " Commands")
        await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="MC-Auth"))

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Hello, world!')


TOKEN = (os.getenv('TOKEN'))

client = Client()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I’ve read about it but can’t find a solution, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback here? The error tells you that something in your code is blocking.

Comment: [WARNING ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\botfotim\bot ig\main.py", line 39, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)

Comment: I see possible multiple errors here: 1) NEVER do things in `on_ready` 2) Define your client at the top of the code and use a different name for your class.